# Yii2 ActiveFrom is not validating properly

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2 ActiveFrom is not validating properly.

This is my view, generated by Yii2 Gii. 
I didn't add anything, but it's still not validating properly.

```
<div class="discussion-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?php $form->field($model, 'userId')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 500]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->textInput(['maxlength' => 500]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'upvotes')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'downvotes')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'commentCount')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'tags')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'createdAt')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'updatedAt')->textInput() ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>
```

The form is ending with the first element like this:

```
<div class="discussion-form">

    <form id="w0" action="/web/discussion/create" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="OUJKTVJKMmhVJB45MThbAVQkehgADmcdXToseREpBQ9cBnILDShGBg==">


<!--?php<div class="form-group field-discussion-title required"-->
<label class="control-label" for="discussion-title">Title</label>
<input type="text" id="discussion-title" class="form-control" name="Discussion[title]" maxlength="500">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</form></div>
    <div class="form-group field-discussion-text required">
<label class="control-label" for="discussion-text">Text</label>
<textarea id="discussion-text" class="form-control" name="Discussion[text]" rows="6"></textarea>

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

This is the problem:

```
<!--?php<div class="form-group field-discussion-title required"-->
```

Comment: So it's not validated properly or you expect different field HTML markup?

Answer (score 0):

Third line:

```
<?php $form->field($model, 'userId')->textInput() ?>
```

should be

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'userId')->textInput() ?>
```

This is really created by gii?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not un-edited :)

Your error is, as *robsch* points out, in the `<?php $form->field($model, 'userId')->textInput() ?>`

The form elements in ActiveForm needs to be echoed out, you can either write `<?php echo $form->....->textInput() ?>` or `<?= $form->....->textInput() ?>`

If you want to remove the ID-field from your form, you have to comment it out or remove it completely. In addition you might have to remove userId from required in your model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['userId', 'title'], 'required'],
        ...
    ]
}
```